# iText avoid to cut tables on page jump

Tags: java, itext

I'm working with a pdf which display many tables. When a table doesn't fit on the rest of the page, iText cut the table and set the rest of them on the next page.

I want that if a table doesn't fit on the rest of the page, then place it on a new page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways to do this; these are three options:

1. Calculate the height of the table, compare it to the space that is left. When you calculate the height of a table before it's added to the document, the height is always 0, UNLESS you define the width of the table using setTotalWidth() and setLockedWidth(). You can find the current Y position on the page using the getVerticalPosition() method (in PdfWriter).
2. Add the table to a ColumnText object, and add the ColumnText object to a rectangle defining the space left on the page in simulation mode. If the content of the ColumnText object couldn't be rendered entirely, trigger a new Page before adding the table for real.
3. If you take the most recent (not yet released) version from the trunk (version 5.3.3-SNAPSHOT) on SourceForge, you can avoid a breaks by using table.keepRowsTogether(0); where 0 is the index of the first row in the table.

Comment: thanks a lot Bruno, this help me a lot :)
PS: I just realize that you wrote the iText book, such a great honor :D

Comment: table.keepRowsTogether is very usefull!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class XX_RPT_D84_AR_Invoice_Printing_GBS extends PdfPageEventHelper{
        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
            Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                    Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("page %d", 1)),
                    (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2, rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\PDF1.pdf"));
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
                BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                BaseColor color = BaseColor.BLACK;
                PdfContentByte cb = null; 
                Phrase[] header = new Phrase[3];
                header [0] = new Phrase("Genpact India");
                header [1] = new Phrase("(A Private Company with Unlimited Liability)");
                header [2] = new Phrase("Registered Office: Delhi Information Technology Park, Shastri Park, Delhi-110053, India");                
                Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED),
                         9, Font.NORMAL);
                boolean isPrinted = false;

                   Image image = Image.getInstance ("src/Logo/logo.png");
                   image.scaleAbsolute(120f, 31f);//image width,height   
                   image.setDpi(-10, -5);
                   image.setSpacingBefore(-15);

                   Image sign = Image.getInstance ("src/Logo/sign.png");
                   sign.scaleAbsolute(100f, 50f);//image width,height 
                   sign.setIndentationLeft(10);
                   PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[]{0.8f,5,1.5f,1.3f,2,2});
                   PdfPCell s_No = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("S No", font));
                   s_No.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
                   s_No.setPaddingTop(2);
                   PdfPCell description = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description", font));
                   description.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
                   description.setPaddingTop(2);
                   PdfPCell ratePerUnit = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Rate Per Unit", font));
                   ratePerUnit.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
                   ratePerUnit.setPaddingTop(2);
                   PdfPCell quantity = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Quantity", font));
                   quantity.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
                   quantity.setPaddingTop(2);
                   PdfPCell inrReferenceAmount = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("INR Reference Amount", font));
                   inrReferenceAmount.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
                   inrReferenceAmount.setPaddingTop(2);
                   PdfPCell amountINR = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Amount INR", font));
                   amountINR.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
                   amountINR.setPaddingTop(2);
                   table.addCell(s_No);
                   table.addCell(description);
                   table.addCell(ratePerUnit);
                   table.addCell(quantity);
                   table.addCell(inrReferenceAmount);
                   table.addCell(amountINR);
                   int i = 1;
                   String value = "123";
                   PdfPCell cell = null;
                   int referenceAmount = 0;
                   int amount = 0;
                   PdfPCell staticData1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Please remit funds via telex transfer/SWIFT as follows to HSBC BANK Limited (Bank address:"+
                           "JMD Regent Square Ist Floor, DLF Phase II, MG Road, Gurgaon 122002, Haryana, India) with the following"+
                           "Instructions:", font));
                   staticData1.setPaddingTop(20);
                   staticData1.setColspan(6);
                   staticData1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                   PdfPCell staticData2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ultimate Beneficiary: Genpact India", font));
                   staticData2.setColspan(6);
                   staticData2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

                   PdfPCell staticData3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("A)For Inward remittances from out side India : Remit by SWIFT MT103 for further credit to Genpact"+
                            "India, Acct no - 054 021365 001 with HSBC India (SWIFT - HSBCINBB) through HSBC Mumbai's account"+
                            "no.000-04417-2, with HSBC Bank, New York, USA having CHIPS code 302755, SWIFT- MRMDUS33 & ABA Routing"+
                            "No. 021-001-088.", font));
                   staticData3.setColspan(6);
                   staticData3.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

                   PdfPCell staticData4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("B)For remittance from within India: Remit to Genpact India HSBC Account No. 054 021365 001, IFSC Code"+
                            "- HSBC0110005.", font));
                   staticData4.setColspan(6);
                   staticData4.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

                   PdfPCell staticData5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("You are requested to send the remittances as per the Payment Term mentioned above."+
                            "Please send the payment notification to :collections.helpdesk@genpact.com"+
                            "Incase of any queries contact : genpactbilling.helpdesk@genpact.com", font));
                   staticData5.setColspan(6);
                   staticData5.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                   PdfPCell staticData6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("FOR & ON BEHALF OF", font));
                   staticData6.setPaddingTop(25);
                   staticData6.setColspan(6);
                   staticData6.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                   PdfPCell staticData7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Genpact India", font));
                   staticData7.setColspan(6);
                   staticData7.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                   PdfPCell staticData8 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("(Private Company with Unlimited liability)", font));
                   staticData8.setColspan(6);
                   staticData8.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                   PdfPCell staticData9 = new PdfPCell(sign);
                   staticData9.setColspan(6);
                   staticData9.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                   PdfPCell staticData10 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Vidut Aggarwal", font));
                   staticData10.setColspan(6);
                   staticData10.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);                
                   PdfPCell staticData11 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is a system generated Invoice and does not require physical signature.", font));
                   staticData11.setColspan(6);
                   staticData11.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

                         Chunk chunk0 = new Chunk("                               ");
                      Chunk chunk = new Chunk("                                                                                                                            ");
                      chunk.setUnderline(+1f,-2f);//1st co-ordinate is for line width,2nd is space between  
                      document.open();
                      cb = writer.getDirectContent(); 
                      cb.setLineWidth(1);
                      MyPageEventListener mpel = new MyPageEventListener();
                      mpel.onEndPage(writer, document);
                      image.setAbsolutePosition(20, 795);
                      document.add(image);
                      document.add(chunk0);
                      document.add(chunk);
                      document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                      cb.saveState();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(280, 810);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("INVOICE");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(20, 775);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Service Tax No : " + "d_ServiceTaxNo");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(320, 788);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Genpact India");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(316, 775);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("(Private Company with unlimited liability)");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(20, 750);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("PAN : " + "d_PAN");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(318, 760);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("d_AddressLine1");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(20, 725);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Category of services: ");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(318, 746);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("d_AddressLine2");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(318, 732);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("d_AddressLine3");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.setColorStroke(color);
                      cb.rectangle(20,715,245,-100);
                      cb.stroke();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(25, 700);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("d_cust_name");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(25, 670);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("d_cust_address");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(318, 715);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("d_pin");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(318, 699);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Tele : " + "d_Telephone");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(318, 685);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Fax : " + "d_Fax");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.setColorStroke(color);
                      cb.rectangle(275,680,300,-80);
                      cb.stroke();
                      cb.setColorStroke(color);
                      cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                      cb.stroke();
                      cb.setColorStroke(color);
                      cb.rectangle(275,680,300,-80);
                      cb.stroke();
                      cb.setColorStroke(color);
                      cb.rectangle(20,610,245,-30);
                      cb.stroke();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(280, 660);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Invoice Number:  " + "d_Invoice_no.");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(280, 645);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Invoice Date:  " + "d_Invoice_date");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(280, 626);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Currency  :   " + "d_Currency");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(280, 605);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Payment Term : " + "d_Payment_term");
                      cb.endText();
                      cb.beginText();
                      cb.moveText(25, 590);
                      cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 10);
                      cb.showText("Attention :  " + "Finance Dept");
```

Comment: The code isn't complete, and there is no explanation of what the code does. Could you please improve?

Answer (score 0):

```
cb.endText();
                      cb.restoreState();
                      document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
                      table.setTotalWidth(555.0f);
                      int sNo = 1;
                      float tableHeight1  =  table.getTotalHeight();
                      System.out.println(tableHeight1);
                      int rowCount = 2;
                      int yAxis = 570;
                      int newPageYAxis = 0;
                      while (i <= 10){
                          for (int l=1;l<=6;l++){
                              if(l==1){
                                  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(sNo), font));
                                  cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT);
                                  cell.setPaddingTop(4); 
                                  sNo++;
                              }else{
                                  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(value, font));
                                  cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT);
                                  cell.setPaddingTop(4);
                              }
                              if(i==10 && l==5){
                                  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(value, font));
                                  cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                                  cell.setPaddingTop(4);
                              }
                              if(i==10 && l==6){
                                  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(value, font));
                                  cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                                  cell.setPaddingTop(4);
                              }
                              if(l==5){
                                  referenceAmount = referenceAmount + Integer.parseInt(value);
                              }
                              if(l==5){
                                  amount = amount + Integer.parseInt(value);
                              }
                              System.out.println(table.getTotalHeight());
                              if(table.getTotalHeight()<=450){
                                  table.addCell(cell);
                                  table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, yAxis, cb);
                                  yAxis = yAxis - 15;
                              }
                              else {
                                  document.newPage();
                                  table.addCell(cell);
                                  table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, yAxis, cb);
                                  newPageYAxis = newPageYAxis + 15;
                              }
                          }
                          i++;
                          rowCount++;
                      }
                      System.out.println(rowCount);
                      PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", font));
                      cell1.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                      cell1.setPaddingTop(4);
                      PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total", font));
                      cell2.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                      cell2.setPaddingTop(4);
                      PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", font));
                      cell3.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                      cell3.setPaddingTop(4);
                      PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", font));
                      cell4.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                      cell4.setPaddingTop(4);
                      PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(referenceAmount), font));
                      cell5.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                      cell5.setPaddingTop(4);
                      PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(amount), font));
                      cell6.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
                      cell6.setPaddingTop(4);
                      System.out.println(table.getLastCompletedRowIndex());
                      if(table.getTotalHeight()<=450){
                          table.addCell(cell1);
                          table.addCell(cell2);
                          table.addCell(cell3);
                          table.addCell(cell4);
                          table.addCell(cell5);
                          table.addCell(cell6);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb);
                          System.out.println("IF: " + table.getTotalHeight());
                          rowCount++;
                      } else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(cell1);
                          table.addCell(cell2);
                          table.addCell(cell3);
                          table.addCell(cell4);
                          table.addCell(cell5);
                          table.addCell(cell6);
                          table.addCell(staticData1);
                          table.addCell(staticData2);
                          table.addCell(staticData3);
                          table.addCell(staticData4);
                          table.addCell(staticData5);
                          table.addCell(staticData6);
                          table.addCell(staticData7);
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb);
                          System.out.println("ELSE: " + table.getTotalHeight());
                          rowCount++;
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          table.addCell(staticData1);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb); 
                          rowCount++;
                      } else if (isPrinted==false) {
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData1);
                          table.addCell(staticData2);
                          table.addCell(staticData3);
                          table.addCell(staticData4);
                          table.addCell(staticData5);
                          table.addCell(staticData6);
                          table.addCell(staticData7);
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb); 
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          table.addCell(staticData2);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb);  
                          rowCount++;
                      }else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData2);
                          table.addCell(staticData3);
                          table.addCell(staticData4);
                          table.addCell(staticData5);
                          table.addCell(staticData6);
                          table.addCell(staticData7);
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb); 
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }  
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          table.addCell(staticData3);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb);  
                          rowCount++;
                      } else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData3);
                          table.addCell(staticData4);
                          table.addCell(staticData5);
                          table.addCell(staticData6);
                          table.addCell(staticData7);
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb); 
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          table.addCell(staticData4);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb); 
                          rowCount++;
                      } else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData4);
                          table.addCell(staticData5);
                          table.addCell(staticData6);
                          table.addCell(staticData7);
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb); 
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          table.addCell(staticData5);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb);  
                          rowCount++;
                      } else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData5);
                          table.addCell(staticData6);
                          table.addCell(staticData7);
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb); 
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          table.addCell(staticData6);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb);  
                          rowCount++;
                      } else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData6);
                          table.addCell(staticData7);
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                           table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb);
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          table.addCell(staticData7);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb);  
                          rowCount++;
                      } else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData7);
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb); 
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb);  
                          rowCount++;
                      }
                      else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData8);
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                           table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb);
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          System.out.println("staticData9");
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb); 
                          rowCount++;
                      } else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData9);
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                           table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb); 
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          System.out.println("staticData10");
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb); 
                          rowCount++;
                      }else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          System.out.println("else staticData10");
                          table.addCell(staticData10);
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                           table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount-1, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb); 
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      if (table.getTotalHeight() <= 450){
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, 0, rowCount, 20, 570, cb); 
                          rowCount++;
                      } else if (isPrinted==false){
                          document.newPage();
                          cb.setColorStroke(color);
                          cb.rectangle(10,90,575,742);
                          cb.stroke();
                          table.addCell(staticData11);
                          table.writeSelectedRows(0, 6, rowCount, -1, 20, (790-newPageYAxis), cb); 
                          isPrinted = true;
                      }
                      System.out.println("Column Index at last " + table.getLastCompletedRowIndex());
                      System.out.println(table.getTotalHeight());           
                         document.close();
                      file.close();
              System.out.println("Pdf created successfully..");
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
    }
```